# When does a search engine learn about a particular user inside a website and display the profile link and /or a Login link along with search results?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, search-engines, web-crawlers, website-promotion

How does Google search engine display user profiles or Login links along with a search results of some websites? because obviously the username or profile name is coming from the server side, so does Google search engine go into the website Database (i.e. Facebook database) and retrieve the link for a particular user?

is that something the website developer have to work on on his end or is this determined by the website popularity by Google itself?

To illustrate my point, photos below are an example:

**This is what you get when you type "facebook" on Google search:**

[image: This is what you get when you type "facebook" on Google search]

**And This is what you get when you type "CNN facebook" on Google search:**

[image: This is what you get when you type "CNN facebook" on Google search]

Comment: You are over thinking this. The first example is a very common example of site links which has been discussed to death here. The second example is just a common search result likely based upon many searches and activity within the SERPs tailoring the more popular and more likely result. Neither of these has anything to do with login or profiles. No magic here.

Comment: Search engines generally have access to public pages. Those facebook pages you shown are pages available to the general public. If google were to show private pages, then it would end up in (yet another) lawsuit for breaching privacy laws because then people could search for social insurance (or social security) numbers of a person on google and instantly find them which then it would be devastating.

Comment: I know what you saying , but even if i type my FB name on google search, my profile will be there on with the results, and I am not popular. but on the other hand, all pages are public on Facebook i think, the profile details inside maybe private but all pages are publicly viewable i think, so my thinking is that google may have an agreement with facebook to go into the database and fetch the profile link from there? I don't know it seems complex, and this doesn't just apply to facebook, this also on twitter, Quora...etc

Comment: It s called machine learning. Google looks for patterns in search queries and SERP results that are successful. Still, no surprise here. I do like your curiosity. It allows us to discuss issues that normally do not get much if any attention. Cheers!!